# Compile-time switch for mutable/immutable lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I am writing a class member function that will take a lambda with a given type `T` in the function argument. My question is: is it possible to overload the member function at compile-time based on the mutability of the argument? Below is the example:

```
// T is a given type for class.
template <typename T>
class Wrapper {

  T _t;      

  // For T&
  template <typename F, typename R = std::result_of_t<F(T&)>>
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<R, void>::value> operator()(F&& f) {
    f(_t);
  }

  // For const T&
  template <typename F, typename R = std::result_of_t<F(const T&)>>
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<R, void>::value> operator()(F&& f) const {
    f(_t);
  }   
};
```

So, what I want is, if the give lambda is with the following signature, the first operator should be invoked.

```
[](T&) {
    ...  
};
```

For constant argument, the second should be invoked.

```
[](const T&) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use non-capturing lambdas only, you can rely on the fact that they decay to pointers to functions.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>

template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
    T _t;      

public:
    auto operator()(void(*f)(T &)) {
        std::cout << "T &" << std::endl;
        return f(_t);
    }

    auto operator()(void(*f)(const T &)) const {
        std::cout << "const T &" << std::endl;
        return f(_t);
    }
};

int main() {
    Wrapper<int> w;
    w([](int &){});
    w([](const int &){});
}
```

Otherwise you can use two overloaded functions as it follows:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>

template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
    T _t;      

    template<typename F>
    auto operator()(int, F &&f)
    -> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(const_cast<const T &>(_t))) const {
        std::cout << "const T &" << std::endl;
        return std::forward<F>(f)(_t);
    }

    template<typename F>
    auto operator()(char, F &&f) {
        std::cout << "T &" << std::endl;
        return std::forward<F>(f)(_t);
    }

public:
    template<typename F>
    auto operator()(F &&f) {
        return (*this)(0, std::forward<F>(f));
    }
};

int main() {
    Wrapper<int> w;
    w([](int &){});
    w([](const int &){});
}
```

Comment: Mmm. This seems good. However, how do I overload this operation with return type from the given lambda? The given f may have its own return type, not only void.

Comment: @Jes Updated. Return type is now deduced.

Comment: Thank you! Let me digest it.

Comment: Adding const is benign and should be done with `static_cast` rather than `const_cast` (which, like `reinterpret_cast`, should be used with extreme caution).

Comment: @ildjarn Why `static_cast` instead of `const_cast`? I mean, in this case the purpose is clear and it is used in an unevaluated context. What are the drawbacks you see in that?

Comment: @skypjack : _This_ usage is safe, but in general `const_cast` can cause UB, so it shouldn't be used where `static_cast` can be used instead. `const_cast` is/should be a red flag indicating dangerous code; _adding_ const is not dangerous.

Comment: @ildjarn It makes sense. I was curious to know if _this_ used was wrong for I didn't understand why. Thank you.